# wxGridSizer / wxPanel : make left/right navigation key behave like shift-tab/tab

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am using a `wxWidget`. I have `panel` with 4 buttons and using `wxGridSizer` to put them in grid. When i go to the rightmost cell of the row and press `Right key`, focus remains on the same widget. Can i set some property where `Right/Left` keys at corner works as tab and shift-tab.

What i want is that user should be able to `circle` through the 4 buttons by just pressing left and right keys. I want to use up/down keys for other purpose.

Here is the code if it helps :

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/grid.h>
#include <wx/sizer.h>
#include <wx/string.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

class ReachItFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
  ReachItFrame(const wxString& title) : wxFrame()
  {
    Create(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(250, 150));
  }
};

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
  bool OnInit()
  {
    ReachItFrame *reachIt = new ReachItFrame(wxT("ReachIt"));
    reachIt->Show(true);
    assert(reachIt->SetTransparent(150));
    assert(reachIt->ShowFullScreen(true, wxFULLSCREEN_ALL));

    wxPanel *panel = new wxPanel(reachIt);
    wxGridSizer *sizer = new wxGridSizer(2, 2, 0, 0);

    wxButton *button1 = new wxButton(panel, wxID_ANY, wxString::FromAscii("1"));
    sizer->Add(button1, wxSizerFlags().Expand());

    wxButton *button2 = new wxButton(panel, wxID_ANY, wxString::FromAscii("2"));
    sizer->Add(button2, wxSizerFlags().Expand());

    wxButton *button3 = new wxButton(panel, wxID_ANY, wxString::FromAscii("3"));
    sizer->Add(button3, wxSizerFlags().Expand());

    wxButton *button4 = new wxButton(panel, wxID_ANY, wxString::FromAscii("4"));
    button4->MoveBeforeInTabOrder(button3);
    sizer->Add(button4, wxSizerFlags().Expand());

    panel->SetSizerAndFit(sizer);

    return true;
  }
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support for this, but you can catch `WXK_RIGHT` and `WXK_LEFT` yourself in your `wxEVT_CHAR` handler and do whatever you want there. You can look at `wxGrid::DoGridProcessTab()` for an example of what you might want to do, e.g. notice the helper `MoveCursor{Left,Right}()` and `GoToCell()` methods used there.

Comment: i meantioned it wrong. i am not using wxGrid but wxGridSizer. In which class should i put wxEVT_CHAR handles

Comment: I added wxEVT_CHAR handler to `Panel` but it is not getting any events.

Comment: Ok, i put the `onchar` handler in `class derived from button` and it is getting the `tab` event. But button is at a lower level in hierarchy and i can not decide which should get the next focus at that level. Skipping the event in button's `OnChar` does not give event to its parent which is panel's onchar

Comment: But you can ask the parent of the button to give you the control to move to, right?

Comment: @Ripi2 But that will be hacky.. Should not i have this logic in the parent about the `next control` ? I will see what happens at the edges with left/right keys.

Comment: Apart from "move to next created" logic of a wxPanel for TAB-key, there's no default logic for any key-event. Why should it? There's nothing hacky in implementing the desired logic on your own.

Comment: @Ripi2 yes but where should that logic go ? in button or in panel ? I think panel should decide. If i could just tell from button that it does not want to handle left/right and let the event propagate upwards to panel where it decides. Think that panel can have other kinds of children.. i donot want to duplicating the logic in every derived class.

Comment: Yeah, I told so in my first comment: "...ask the parent..." Depending on the parent's answer you can let the event to be handled in parent's class or just move focus to other control. See VZ's suggested examples.