# EVT_KEY_DOWN and EVT_CHAR not hitting

Tags: wxwidgets

I have two classes derived from wxFrame and wxPanel respectively. I have attached a handle on `EVT_KEY_DOWN` and `EVT_CHAR`. But none of them is hitting.

I have tried both `EventTable` and dynamic `Connect` approach.
wx

```
class ReachItFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
  ReachItFrame(const wxString& title) : wxFrame()
  {
    SetEvtHandlerEnabled(true);
    Create(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(250, 150));
  }

  void OnChar(wxKeyEvent & event)
  {
    std::cout << "In ReachItFrame.. onChar" << std::endl;
    event.Skip();
  }

  void OnExit(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
  {
    std::cout << "Onexit " << std::endl;
  }

  wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(ReachItFrame, wxFrame)
  EVT_MENU(wxID_EXIT, ReachItFrame::OnExit)
  EVT_CHAR(ReachItFrame::OnChar)
  EVT_KEY_DOWN(ReachItFrame::OnChar)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

class ReachItPanel : public wxPanel
{
public:
  ReachItPanel(wxWindow *parent) : wxPanel(parent)
  {
    std::cout << "In ReachItPanel : " << std::endl;
    SetEvtHandlerEnabled(true);
    Connect(wxEVT_CHAR, wxKeyEventHandler(ReachItPanel::OnChar), NULL, this);
    Connect(wxEVT_KEY_DOWN, wxKeyEventHandler(ReachItPanel::OnChar), NULL, this);
  }
  virtual ~ReachItPanel() {}
  void OnChar(wxKeyEvent& event)
  {
    std::cout << "In OnChar : " << event.GetKeyCode() << std::endl;
    event.Skip();
  }
};

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
  bool OnInit()
  {
    ReachItFrame *reachIt = new ReachItFrame(wxT("ReachIt"));
    reachIt->Show(true);
    assert(reachIt->SetTransparent(150));
    assert(reachIt->ShowFullScreen(true, wxFULLSCREEN_ALL));
    wxGridSizer *sizer = new wxGridSizer(2, 2, 0, 0);

    wxButton *button1 = new wxButton(reachIt, wxID_ANY, wxString::FromAscii("1"));
    sizer->Add(button1, wxSizerFlags().Expand());

    wxButton *button2 = new wxButton(reachIt, wxID_ANY, wxString::FromAscii("2"));
    sizer->Add(button2, wxSizerFlags().Expand());

    wxButton *button3 = new wxButton(reachIt, wxID_ANY, wxString::FromAscii("3"));
    sizer->Add(button3, wxSizerFlags().Expand());

    wxButton *button4 = new wxButton(reachIt, wxID_ANY, wxString::FromAscii("4"));
    button4->MoveBeforeInTabOrder(button3);
    sizer->Add(button4, wxSizerFlags().Expand());

    // Initial view.
    reachIt->SetSizerAndFit(sizer);
    sizer->Layout();
    reachIt->Layout();

    // create panel in place of second button.
    ReachItPanel *panel = new ReachItPanel(reachIt);
    ReachItPanel *innerPanel = new ReachItPanel(panel);
    wxButton *button5 = new wxButton(innerPanel, wxID_ANY, wxString::FromAscii("5"));
    wxButton *button6 = new wxButton(innerPanel, wxID_ANY, wxString::FromAscii("5"));
    wxButton *button7 = new wxButton(innerPanel, wxID_ANY, wxString::FromAscii("5"));
    wxButton *button8 = new wxButton(innerPanel, wxID_ANY, wxString::FromAscii("5"));
    wxGridSizer *innerPanelSizer = new wxGridSizer(2,2,0,0);
    innerPanelSizer->Add(button5, wxSizerFlags().Expand());
    innerPanelSizer->Add(button6, wxSizerFlags().Expand());
    innerPanelSizer->Add(button7, wxSizerFlags().Expand());
    innerPanelSizer->Add(button8, wxSizerFlags().Expand());
    innerPanel->SetSizerAndFit(innerPanelSizer);

    wxStaticBox *box1 = new wxStaticBox(panel, wxID_ANY, wxString::FromAscii("5b1"));
    wxStaticBox *box2 = new wxStaticBox(panel, wxID_ANY, wxString::FromAscii("5b2"));
    wxStaticBox *box3 = new wxStaticBox(panel, wxID_ANY, wxString::FromAscii("5b3"));

    wxGridSizer *panelSizer = new wxGridSizer(2,2,0,0);
    panelSizer->Add(innerPanel, wxSizerFlags().Expand());
    panelSizer->Add(box1, wxSizerFlags().Expand());
    panelSizer->Add(box2, wxSizerFlags().Expand());
    panelSizer->Add(box3, wxSizerFlags().Expand());

    panel->SetSizerAndFit(panelSizer);

    // Replace button2 with panel.
    sizer->Replace(button2, panel, false);
    button2->Hide();
    sizer->Layout();
    reachIt->Layout();

    // Replace panel with button2
    // sizer->Replace(panel, button2, false);
    // panel->Hide();
    // button2->Show();
    // sizer->Layout();
    // reachIt->Layout();

    // button3->SetFocus();
    return true;
  }
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
```

My UI has multiple buttons. When i press tab, i can go through the buttons. But i want to do some custom work on left/right keys.

Hence, i want to capture keys. But my handles are not hitting.

Comment: when you press the keys in question what control has the focus? If you want to catch cursor keys you need to Bind the events to the button itself.

Comment: @Igor You are right, button is getting the event.

Comment: so this is resolved?

Comment: the original question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46502297/wxgridsizer-wxpanel-make-left-right-navigation-key-behave-like-shift-tab-tab/46504279#46504279

but yes this is resolved.